# Converting newline character in char array to string?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

```
   char[] charArray = {'\n'};
   String str = String.valueOf(charArray);
   System.out.println(str);
```

So I want to obtain a string of the newline character that is in the array.
However, with this code, the output is simply a blank space. How can I get 
String str= "\n" ?

Comment: clarify a bit you want to print \n on screen or replace new line character from input with \n on screen?

Comment: I simply want to print out "\n" not as actual whitespace but as if i was printing any other string like "hi"

Answer (score 2):

'\n' is the encoding for a newline character. Perhaps you want:

```
String str = "\\n"
```

or perhaps you want

```
char[] charArray = {'\\','n'};
String str = String.valueOf(charArray)
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Going to edit that in the original post

Comment: So that means I can't use valueOf(charArray) because that immediately interprets the newline as whitespace (as it should)